# Is it possible to import a netlist from Multisim into Kicad?

Tags: kicad, multisim

So at the moment I'm using two different programs for modeling circuits. Multisim and KiCad. I use Multisim because it allows me to do SPICE simulations, something that KiCad doesn't allow me to do. I then need to route the circuit on a PCB, something that Multisim by itself can not do. That's where KiCad comes in. I've used KiCad before to route circuits on a PCB and it's worked out well for me. The problem is the netlist that Multisim outputs doesn't work when I try to import it in KiCad. What I think is going on is that the .net file type used by KiCad runs a different format than the one in Multisim. Is there a way to convert these two files so they are compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried exporting to previous multisim formats? I dont use it but, perhaps, it has the feature to export to other versions, or even other formats, like the gerber format (this can be read with gerbview).
I personally what to do its to simulate in [gEDA](http://www.geda-project.org/) thats a full suite to simulate (ngspice) and make the pcb doing in  [pcb](http://pcb.geda-project.org/pcb-cvs/pcb.html) and other things.

See ya!